# PWM-stimulated N-channel MOSFET unexpectedly always on

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, pwm, duty-cycle

Electronics!

I would appreciate help with the following problem:

**Goal:**
Get 12V PWM-modulated from a microcontroller-generated 5V PWM.

**Elements:**
• IRLML2502, n-channel FET  - [Datasheet](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irlml2502.pdf)
• Resistors R1 (56 Ohm) and R2 (6K8 Ohm)

**Reduced schematics:**

[image: reduced schematic]

**Problem:**
Drain is always around 12V (100% duty cycle) - independent of gate duty-cycle.
All my IRLML2502 show the same behaviour.

**What I checked:**
• Scope shows correct duty cycle(s) on gate.
• Gate voltage either 0V or 5V.
• Source voltage is 12V as expected.
• Checked pin-correctness various times.

**My Request:**
Please tell me, if you see any obvious problems.
Please point me in a direction to perform further checks.
Please be kind, i am no native electronics guy :)

Thank you very much for your help!

Best regards,
R2D2

Comment: I think you have your circuit backwards (and it's drawn upside down, which is really confusing, and please, use real component symbols not drawings of the component package)

Comment: Hint: There's a reason why CMOS circuits have the positive supply on "Vdd" and the negative supply on "Vss".

Comment: @Majenko Schematics will improve as soon is a understand Eagle better, promise! Could you elaborate on "you have your circuit backwards"? I know this might sound silly, but i am really no electronics guy...

Comment: @R2D2 My answer explains all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using your MOSFET backwards.  your circuit, re-drawn the right way up, with proper symbols, is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpBU4D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note: I have added the body diode specifically to highlight the problem.

An N-channel MOSFET should be used as a *low side switch*, not a *high side switch*.  That specific MOSFET, the gate has to be at least 1.2V higher than the source for it to switch on.  Since your source is 12V that means your PWM signal would have to reach as high as 13.2V to turn the MOSFET on.  Not that it'd make much difference, since the diode bypasses the MOSFET anyway.

So, either turn the MOSFET over and use it to switch the GND wire of whatever you're switching, or use a P-channel MOSFET to switch the 12V.

For low side switching the circuit would be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBtyLX.png)</sup>

Comment: Just a minor correction: N-channel MOSFETs ARE sometimes used as high-side drivers, although the drain goes to the positive supply and the source goes to the load. Special gate drivers are used to bring the gate voltage above the supply voltage to turn it on (as you noted).